# Using Python 3.6.1. Syntax error in print statement

Tags: python

```
# Example for Algorithm Case Study
def naïve(a, b):
    x = a
    y = b
    z = 0
    while x > 0:
        z = z + y
        x = x - 1
    return z

print naïve(4,5)
```

The output should be 20. Because of syntax error in print statement, I     am not getting the answer.

Comment: In py3, print is a function. `print('something')`

Comment: You're probably using Python 3. You need to use parenthesis as `print` would be a function.

Answer (score 2):

`print` in Python 3 is a function, meaning you need to call it with parenthesis:

```
print(naïve(4,5))
```

Comment: In Python 2 (we don't know what version the OP is using), this is still a syntax error, but for different reasons...

Comment: Check out the title - OP is using 3.6.1.

Comment: Oh yes, for some reason I only examined the tags

Comment: Hi All Thanks. print(naïve(4,5)) worked.